# Blank attachment sent by SMTP Sampler

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 thread groups. After first thread group is executed, the second thread group will send an email with SMTP sampler along with attachment of the result file generated from the first thread group. I am receiving the email, but it is blank.

-Test Plan (Execute thread group one by one)

-Thread Group1

-Multiple http requests

-View Results Tree (generate result file)

-Thread Group 2

-SMTP Sampler to send the email with result file (multipart)

I have tried with teardown thread group again the same result. I am running in GUI mode and want result of first thread group to be sent via email after thread group 1 execution is completed.

Jmeter version 5.1.1

Running on windows 7.

TestPlan Snapshot:-
[image]

TestPlan

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Smoke Test Suite Prod" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">true</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Smoke Test Suite Prod" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testclass="GenericController" testname="Browse" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Browse Page1" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.google.com</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree/>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Browse Page 2" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.yahoo.com</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>true</encoding>
              <assertions>false</assertions>
              <subresults>false</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <fileName>true</fileName>
              <hostname>true</hostname>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">Smoke_Test_Results.csv</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <TestAction guiclass="TestActionGui" testclass="TestAction" testname="Pause Action" enabled="true">
          <intProp name="ActionProcessor.action">1</intProp>
          <intProp name="ActionProcessor.target">0</intProp>
          <stringProp name="ActionProcessor.duration">5000</stringProp>
        </TestAction>
        <hashTree/>
        <SmtpSampler guiclass="SmtpSamplerGui" testclass="SmtpSampler" testname="Email Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.server"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.serverPort"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.mailFrom"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.replyTo"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverTo"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverCC"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverBCC"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.subject">Smoke Test Report</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.suppressSubject">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.include_timestamp">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.message">Hi All,

Please find the attached Test Report with Thread Group.

</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.plainBody">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.attachFile">XXXXXPathXXX\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\Smoke_Test_Results.csv</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useSSL">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useStartTLS">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.trustAllCerts">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.enforceStartTLS">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useLocalTrustStore">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.trustStoreToUse"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.tlsProtocols"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="SMTPSampler.use_eml">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.emlMessageToSend"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useAuth">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.password"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.username"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.messageSizeStatistics">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.enableDebug">true</stringProp>
          <collectionProp name="SMTPSampler.headerFields"/>
        </SmtpSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <PostThreadGroup guiclass="PostThreadGroupGui" testclass="PostThreadGroup" testname="tearDown Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">6</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">5</stringProp>
      </PostThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <TestAction guiclass="TestActionGui" testclass="TestAction" testname="Pause Action" enabled="true">
          <intProp name="ActionProcessor.action">1</intProp>
          <intProp name="ActionProcessor.target">0</intProp>
          <stringProp name="ActionProcessor.duration">5000</stringProp>
        </TestAction>
        <hashTree/>
        <SmtpSampler guiclass="SmtpSamplerGui" testclass="SmtpSampler" testname="Email Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.server"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.serverPort"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.mailFrom"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.replyTo"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverTo"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverCC"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.receiverBCC"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.subject">Smoke Test Report</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.suppressSubject">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.include_timestamp">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.message">Hi All,

Please find the attached Test Report with tearDown.

Thanks &amp; Regards,
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.plainBody">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.attachFile">XXXXXPathXXX\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\Smoke_Test_Results.csv</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useSSL">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useStartTLS">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.trustAllCerts">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.enforceStartTLS">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useLocalTrustStore">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.trustStoreToUse"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.tlsProtocols"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="SMTPSampler.use_eml">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.emlMessageToSend"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.useAuth">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.password"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.username"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.messageSizeStatistics">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="SMTPSampler.enableDebug">true</stringProp>
          <collectionProp name="SMTPSampler.headerFields"/>
        </SmtpSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Have you selected Run Thread Group Consecutively in Test Plan checkbox?

Comment: Yes, by "Execute thread group one by one" I mean the same. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use Listeners during your JMeter load test execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), they should only be used for tests development and/or debugging. Listeners don't add any value, but only consume resources.

In particular your case [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener opens the result file in such a way that it cannot be used by other programs, including JMeter itself.

The solution would be:

1. Remove all the listeners from your test plan
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```
3. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t your_test.jmx -l Smoke_Test_Results.csv
   ```
4. That's it, upon test completion you should get the email with the results.

Comment: ..Thanks for the inputs. View results is only for debugging. I will try this in non-GUI mode..but is it possible in GUI mode? My requirement, is for GUI, it is actual not load testing but more of functional testing...I will try with both.

Comment: In Non-GUI, it is working as explained in the above approach. Vote for that, but still waiting if there is way to achieve in GUI mode.

Comment: Ok...I tried with Simple data writer and autoflush in GUI..and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scope of JMeter Elements are properly aligned.

1. Create 2 Thread Groups in Test Plan and select Run Thread Group Consecutively in Test Plan
2. First Thread Group will execute the Sampler and create the output/result file from View Result Tree. Save it to disk
3. Second Thread Group will execute SMTP Sampler with attachment.

**Note : Attachment name can also be parameterized.**

Practical example shown below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have provided the snapshot for my plan. Let me know if you find any issue or idea by looking into it.

Comment: Try below things:
- Just run SMTP Sampler with any random file from disk. Check whether you receive email with attachment.
- If point 1 is successful for you, now run the Thread Group 1 [only] and see whether the CSV is getting generated properly with data.
- If point 1 and 2 are successful, now run both together with a delay in Thread Group 2 starting.

Comment: First 2 points working. But, together even with delay is not working. Is it working on your side?

Comment: Yes it is working for me, just follow the steps shown in answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working for me. Also, your first screenshot will create a file in bin and second is sending a different file.

Comment: I am running from the same folder. It is picking up the file and sending email with attachment. It does not create file in bin folder, file will be created from where you are starting jmeter. Just pickup the path from where your result is generated.

Comment: Can you paste the content of .jmx in the question? Edit the jmx file in Notepad++ and paste the full content in the question.

Comment: I have attached the required file for reference.